# How does the javascript file know where the dependencies are after using npm install?

Tags: javascript, html, npm

I have received 1 javascript file, lets call it "neededjavascriptfile.js", and it has a package.json file.
This javascript file will need to be run in a html index file, where I will need to use some functions from the javascript file.

I have ran "npm install --omit=dev" in the folder, and it has downloaded the required .js files and other files, and put them in a "node_modules" folder.

How does the javascript file know how to find these files? The node_modules folder seems to have a bunch of files, some which are probably not required.

What I have currently done is to go into each and every folder, and put the "filename.min.js", into my root folder, then I have included all the files in my "index.html" like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filename2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="neededjavascriptfile.js"></script>
```

There must be a better, and more correct way to do this?

Comment: Mostly it does what you're doing right now. Only you're doing it manually. If you use something like webpack or browserify you can just `require()` it or `import` it and they will find the files for you and bundle them together with your code. Most can even do tree-shaking and remove code from the libraries that are never used.

Comment: @slebetman 

I looked into a bit of codebunders after these answers, and browserify, and parcel seems to be the easiest to use for a beginner. Does browserify support the new import statements? It does not seem like it is?

Answer (score 0):

> How does the javascript file know how to find these files?

It doesn't.

`npm` is the *Node* Package Manager. It is designed for use with Node.js which, in turn, is designed to use the *node_modules* directory when you import modules without an explicit path.

Browsers do not have that feature.

If you want to involve `npm` in your build process for JS targetting browsers then you need to do something to give the JS files URLs on your web server.

Typically that involves the use of a bundler like Parcel, Vite, or Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: yes, there is a better way. Use a build tool like Rollup or Webpack to create a bundle that the web server can serve.

The long answer: the Javascript that is running inside a web page doesn't know anything about `node_modules`. There are two levels at work here: the first one is your development environment; the second is the deliverable that you want to create and execute (the web page, in this case).

When you use `npm` you are developing a node application. If you run it with node, it knows where to find the dependencies in `node_modules`.

On the other hand, if you include scripts in a web page (and remember this is happening on another machine), all the browser knows is how to reach the web server and the path you define in `src` is relative to the root folder of the server. You could do something "ugly" like changing the `src` attribute so that it points to `../node_modules/<etc>`, or something like that (assuming the folder is accessible to the web server), but that is not recommended. That is why you have to manually do what a build tool like Rollup is designed to do (copying the files in the root folder, in this example).